# How to add two adjacent columns together then display the new value in the leftmost column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to add two adjacent columns together then display that value in the first of the two columns, clear the values in the second column, and repeat whenever a new number is added to the second column. I don't mind if this is linked to a button or just straight from an input.

I tried this:

```
function doTest() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var num1 = ss.getRange("D7:D116").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("E7:E116").getValue();

ss.getRange("D7:D116").setValue(num1+num2);
ss.getRange("E7:E116").clearContent();
}
```

It's the basic idea but it only prints the very first sum value into every cell, instead of applying the formula into every row values.

I've lurked on a few similar posts but they seem to be about reprinting data from one column to another in a different sheet or into a different workbook. 
An array formula may work but I'm stuck using 2 columns and i cant lose the values.

An array formula I looked at was

```
=ArrayFormula( IF( ROW( B:B ) < 1 , "" , IF( LEN( C:C ) * LEN( B:B ) , B:B + C:C & Clear C:C, IFERROR( 1/0 ) ) ) )
```

I got this off Stack Overflow and it works the first time. However, it requires 3 columns and it won't add the values cumulatively. I also don't understand enough about arrays/java to fix it.

Any help would be amazing. I'd ask that you add comments to each action so I can follow along with any script.

An example of the sheet I'm working on =>>

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X1oGwWda8p0AJjAGxALZ1F5cJPzszqPxv6UnBlH0KwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the Apps Script developer reference, review the entries for `getValues()` and `setValues(values[][])`, and contrast with the methods you use here (`getValue()` and `setValue(value)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `getValues()` and `setValues()`
- Loop over each row to find the sum

```
function doTest() {
  //@OnlyCurrentDoc
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = ss.getRange("D7:E116");
  var val = rng.getValues(); //getRangeValues
  //Loop over each row
  for(row=0;row<val.length;row++) {
    val[row][0] = val[row][0]+val[row][1];// Current row's First Column[0] value = first column+ second column
    val[row][1] =''; //set Second Column value null
  }
  rng.setValues(val)
}
```